# Javascript Discord bot doesn't read the full array

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The relevant part of my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')
const client = new Discord.Client()

var forbidden = fs.readFileSync('forbidden.txt').toString().split("\n")

client.on('message', async (msg) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < forbidden.length; i++) {
        if (msg.content.toLowerCase().includes(forbidden[i])) {
            msg.channel.send("Don't say that :rage:")
        }
    }
}
```

Basically i want the bot to read the txt file and see if any words on there are in the sent message. However, the bot will only react to the last word in the txt file. What have i done wrong?

edit: forgot to add, i tried printing some words from the file and it worked fine, but the loop won't work.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with your mismatched braces?

Comment: oops, that was a copy paste mistake. It was right on the actual code.

Comment: Can you confirm that each word from the array is read correctly inside the loop? Also, you should `return` if a word is found so you don't get spammed if there's multiple.

Comment: i can make it print all the words using the same array and loop, but it still wont work

Comment: Try printing out `msg.content` to make sure that it received the message properly. Also, another possibility is that forbidden.txt uses CRLF line endings, in which case you should change them to LF line endings or split on `\r\n`

Comment: As opposed to a txt file, a JSON file would probably be easier. You could simply have `{ words: ["stupid", "dumb"] }` and then in your code do `const { words } = require('./forbidden.json')`, and you'd have an array already (no need to read the file and transform it into a string, `require` does that for you).

Comment: just changin to json made it work, thanks everyone!